# C# WPF Как в List View заменить ListViewItem на класс-наследник?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть например класс-наследник от ListViewItem - AdvancedListViewItem. В XAML я могу задать

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.Items>
    <model:AdvancedListViewItem/>
    <model:AdvancedListViewItem/>
    ...
  </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

но мне нужен Binding к ListView.ItemsSource, а он создает обычные ListViewItem,
как изменить тип создаваемых елементов списка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно создать наследника ListView и перегрузить у него метод `GetContainerForItemOverride`:

```
public class AdvancedListView : ListView
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new AdvancedListViewItem();
    }
}
```